# Bin Packing with Overflow

Tags: algorithm, memory-management, bin-packing

I have N bins (homogenous or heterogeneous in size, depending on variant of task) in which I am trying to fit M items (always heterogeneous in size). Items can be larger than a single bin and are allowed to overflow to the next bin(s) (but no wrap around from bin N-1 to 0).

The more bins an item spans, the higher its allocation cost.

I want to minimize the overall allocation cost of fitting all M into N bins.

Everything is static. It is guaranteed that all M fit in N.

I think I am looking for a variant of the Bin Packing algorithm. But any hints towards an existing solution/approximation/good heuristic are appreciated.

My current approach looks like this:

```
sort items by size
for i in items:
  for b in bins:
     try allocation of i starting at b
     if allocation valid:
       record cost
  do allocation of i in b with lowest recorded cost
  update all b fill level
```

So basically a greedy by size approach with O(MxNxC) runtime, where C~"longest allocation across banks" (`try allocation` takes C time).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest dynamic programming for the exact solution. To make it easier to visualize, assume each bin's size is the length of an array of cells. Since they are contiguous, you can visualize them as a contiguous set of arrays, e.g.

```
|xxx|xx|xxx|xxxx|
```

the delimiters of the arrays are || and the positions in the arrays are given by x. so this has 4 arrays, arr_0 of size 3, arr_1 of size 2 and so on.
If you place an item at position i, it will ocuppy position i to i+(h-1), where h is the size of the items. E.g. if items are of size h=5, and you place an item at position 1, you would get

```
|xb|bb|bbx|xxxx|
```

One trick to use is that if we introduce the additional constraint that the items need to be inserted “in order”, i.e. the first inserted is the leftmost inserted item, the second is the second-leftmost inserted item, etc. then this problem will have the same optimal solution solution as the original one (since we can just take the optimal solution and insert it in order).

Consider pos(k-1,i) to be the optimal position to insert the k-th object
Given that we the k-1th object ended at (I-1). opt_c(k-i,i) the optimal extra-cost of inserting the k-1…N pieces, given that the k-1th object ended at (I-1).

Then pos(N-1,i) can be easily calculated by running through the cells and calculating the extra-cost (and even easier by noting that at least one of the borders should match up with pos(N-1,i), but to make analysis easier we will evaluate the extra-cost each of the I…NumCells-h). opt_c(N-1,i) equals this extra-cost.

Similarly,

```
pos(N-2,i) = argmin_x extra_cost(x,i, pos(N-1,x+h)) + opt(N-1,x+h)
```

Where extra_cost is the extra_cost(x,i,j) of inserting at x, given that the last inserted object ended at I-1 and the next inserted  object will start at j.

And by substituting x = opt(N-2,i)

```
 opt(N-2,i) = extra_cost(opt(N-2,i),I, pos(N-1,opt(N-2,i)+h)) + opt(N-1,opt(N-2,i)+h)
```

By induction, for all  1<=W<N-1

```
 pos(W,i) = argmin_x extra_cost(x,i, pos(W+1,x+h)) + opt(W+1,x+h)
And
 opt(W,i) = extra_cost( pos(W,i),I, pos(N+1, pos(W,i)+h)) + opt(N-1, pos(W,i)+h)
```

And your final result is given by the minimal over `i` of all `opt(0,i)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I have to admit that you lost me already at `Consider pos(k-1,i) to be the optimal...`. Could you elaborate on the syntax of `pos(x,y)`, as well as on the use of lower and upper case characters like i vs I, k and N. Thanks!

Comment: So after you have inserted the k-1th object, you know the position where it ends. this would be the (i-1)-th position.  you can choose to insert the k-th object on any position after and including i. pos(k-1,i) will be the position with minimal cost given those constraints. pos(N-1, i) is easy to compute since it just involves checking each of the positions from i to N for the minimum extra cost. So what you do is calculate pos(N-1,i) for all i=1...N. Then you use the induction formula to calculate pos(N-2,i) for all  i=.... and repeat until you get to the last object pos(0,i).

Comment: N,M are defined from your question, h is the predefined size of one item. i and j model positions on the contiguous set of arrays(what they mean in each particular instance is explained above). The approach here is to use backward induction from the last inserted item to the first inserted item.